# MongoDB increase disk on the VM

Tags: mongodb

My problem is with Mongo eating up space on the disk.

Reading a few blogs no the web - I was certain - a `repair` would save me time as this would free up mongo's reserved space. But attempting a repair throws this error because I am at 90% disk usage :

```
db.repairDatabase()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot repair database my_d_b having size: 347673198592 (bytes) because free disk space is: 42874580992 (bytes)"
}
```

Then I tried the next step which is compacting every collection in the database using :

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) {
  print('Compacting: ' + collectionName);
  db.runCommand({ compact: collectionName });
});
```

This reduced my disk usage by just 1%.

Now I can easily pause my apps from writing to this mongo database. I don't want to use any replset approach etc. I want to just move it to a bigger disk and move forward. I have already mounted an extra disk which 2.5times the size. I am not finding concrete steps to move the data and change mongo configuration and then start mongo process.

My repairs and compactions may be failing because they need space to operate as per my understading. If I can move this data to new disk and point mongo to the new disk, I will be good.

This is what I want to achieve - would appreciate a little direction.

Comment: It sounds like you have a standalone server and are OK stopping `mongod` ? If so, the most direct approach would be to copy the contents of your current [`dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) to the a directory on the new disk: stop `mongod`, copy the contents of your `dbPath` to a new directory, update `dbPath` in your configuration file to point to this new directory, and finally restart `mongod`. As far as trying to reduce existing storage usage: can you confirm the specific version of MongoDB and storage engine are you using?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to configure a replicaset?

Comment: @Stennie You should post this as an answer; it'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: That worked for me @Stennie

Comment: @VinceBowdren - i just dont want to go that route for now, may be in future. Can afford a down-time - wanted to keep this simple.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I thought there might be more context to address based on the version of MongoDB and storage engine in use, but it sounds like the suggested approach worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a standalone MongoDB server and can tolerate downtime, the most direct approach would be to copy the contents of your current `dbPath` to a directory on the new disk:

- Stop `mongod`
- Copy the contents of your `dbPath` to a directory on the new disk
- Update `dbPath` in your configuration file to point to this new directory
- Finally, restart `mongod`